# Misunderstanding about the spin part of the Jahn Teller effect

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

In the paper [*Stability if Polyatomic Molecules in Degenerate Electronic States II - Spin Degeneracy*](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1938.0008) the author wrote:

> Thus a twofold degeneracy cannot produce instability for a molecule containing an odd number of electrons with spin.

It is really disturbing for me as I'm looking to the Jahn-Teller effect being strong on the $e_g$ orbitals when there is a odd number of electrons on it.

Comment: I haven't got a chance to delve in this paper in detail, but it seems to be referring to the specific case of twofold *spin* degeneracy (for example an single electron being spin up or down produces two degenerate states). $e_g$ describes the spatial symmetry and it can still produce a Jahn-Teller distortion. @Tom